# How to get call on an extension, which is registered when a call towards it reach Kamailio

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, kamailio

I am using **Kamailio 4.4** as the proxy with my **Asterisk** server. I am trying to develop a scenario where an extension gets registered on asterisk via Kamailio when it receives a push notification. This push notification is sent to the sip extension when a call towards this extension reaches to the Kamailio.

For example, suppose there is two SIP extension( *extension 1 and extension 2*) registered on Asterisk via Kamailio. When a call from extension 1 reaches the asterisk, it forwards the **INVITE** request towards extension 2 via Kamailio.Kamailio will try to forward it to extension 2. suppose the extension 2 is not able to receive the **INVITE** request from Kamailio. When extension two receive a push notification, it will register on asterisk. 
So I need to get the call on extension 2 through the new registration.

We are trying to simulate registration of extension to the asterisk when receiving the push notification.
First, we registered extension 2 and disconnected the network. Then we tried to register the same extension when a call from extension 1 reaches to Kamailio. This is a simulation of push-based registration since an extension that receives the push will attempt to register when an incoming call is received.

When asterisk sends INVITE request to Kamailio, it immediately responded with **100 trying** provisional response. This 100 response by Kamailio towards asterisk prevents asterisk from re-transmitting the INVITE.
Then Kamailio tried to send and retransmit the packet to extension 2, which does not have network access. This extension 2 was on port number *24071*. Even after successful registration(*in port 59995*) of the extension 2, Kamailio continued to transmit the packets to the old port.

After that, we have configured Kamailio in a way that it won't send an immediate provisional reply(*100 trying* ) for **INVITE** request.
Here Kamailio is not immediately sending **100 trying** message to Asterisk. This forces Asterisk to re-transmit. Asterisk was found to retransmit the same packets. However, even after the successful registration of extension 2, asterisk continued to send the old invite to Kamailio not the new one to the latest port.

This is the problem for me since push relies on the **INVITE** reaching the phone at the correct port number.

So, is there other good approaches to solve this issue?

One thing I would like to try is modifying the pending **INVITE** request towards old registered port with the new port details when new registration reaches to Kamailio. Can I get the ongoing requests from Kamailio? 
Please suggest a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any kamailio config availible do similar thing.

You have save into location and consult it when do call.

However if you need really scalable platform you SHOULD NOT forward register requests to asterisk at all.

If kamailio send invite to wrong port, likly that mean you have TWO records in location.